How to remove a matrix with duplicated rows in R?
I need a function that returns non-duplicated rows of a matrix.
For instance, to turn matrix
matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)

of which row 1, 3, are duplicates into a matrix
matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)

where every row is unique, I need a function that returns a vector of indices c(1,2,4)

Did you mean matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)? I get errors with your code as provided.
